# how to connect from Flash Media Server 3.5 to Zend_Amf

Tags: flash, zend-framework, flash-media-server, zend-amf

i want to be able to connect from flash media server 3.5 to Zend_Amf (latest ZendFramework version). i tried doing the following:

```
function amfresponder ( ) {
this.onResult = function (result) {
    trace("Success: " + String(result));
};
this.onStatus = function (fault) {
    trace("Error: "+ fault.description);
};
};


application.onConnect = function(client) {

myResponder = new amfresponder();

connection = new NetConnection();

connection.connect("http://localhost/AmfServer.php");
trace("checking connection");
connection.call("isConnected",myResponder);

return true;    
}
```

i see in the apache access log that a request for AmfServer.php was made
but nothing is returned, not even an error message. on the fms admin log i only see 'checking connection'.

#### update

A different approach:

```
application.isFine_Status = function(info) {
  for(var item in info) {
    trace(item + " " + info[item]);
  } 
}

application.isFine_Result = function(res) {
    trace(res);
}

application.onAppStart = function() {
trace("application started");
NetServices.setDefaultGatewayUrl("http://localhost/AmfServer.php");
    this.gatewayconn = NetServices.createGatewayConnection();   
    this.pservice = this.gatewayconn.getService('PrivateFunc',this);
    this.pservice.isFine();
}
```

The Zend_Amf class is:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.realpath(__DIR__.'/../').PATH_SEPARATOR.realpath(__DIR__.'/../../include/PEAR-R2'));

require_once('Zend/Amf/Server.php');
require_once('PrivateFunc.php');

$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass('PrivateFunc','PrivateFunc');
$response = $server->handle();
echo $response;
```

on both cases i have no results what so ever. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this code below

setClass("PrivateFunc");

  // needed to start the server
  $handle = $server->handle();
  echo($handle);
  //echo($server->handle()); 
?>

Answer (score 0):

ok so after a lot of research it seems that currently it is not possible to do a proper connection from adobe flash media server to zend_amf.

i solved the issue by moving from adobe flash media server to it's free solution red5.
red5 is java based which provides a very strong programming language, so i converted the relevant code from php to java, and everything (db manipulation) is done in red5 and php is not needed all.

Comment: i saw some more information in http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=955694 but still no proper solution